# how to get column data from an entity model?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to get one column of data and stuff it in a combobox but couldn't get it to work. Can anybody help me out with this please?

Code:

```
test_DataEntities db = new test_DataEntities();
DataGrid test = new DataGrid();
test.ItemsSource = db.testTbls;
cmbWorkOrder.ItemsSource = test.Columns[2];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
cmbWorkOrder.ItemsSource = (test.ItemsSource as IEnumerable<testTblEntity>)
    .Select(t => t.PropertyToDisplayInComboBox);
```

It returns an `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is the type of the property you want to display in the combo box (a `string` for instance). I would expect that binding to `test.ItemsSource` will execute the query to fetch the entities from the DB into memory and then the binding to `cmbWorkOrder.ItemsSource` only reads its data from the in-memory collection and doesn't hit the database again. Sure though I am not.

**Edit**

Perhaps this is a bit cleaner:

```
test_DataEntities db = new test_DataEntities();
DataGrid test = new DataGrid();
List<testTblEntity> list = db.testTbls.ToList(); // executes the query
test.ItemsSource = list;
cmbWorkOrder.ItemsSource = list.Select(t => t.PropertyToDisplayInComboBox);
```

You have control now when the query actually gets executed. In the first example it would depend on the binding engine when it will bind the grid and when the combo box to your data which might depend on the order of the controls in XAML (assuming it's WPF).

Comment: Actually I just figured it out after battling for an hour.       Code: var query = from a in db.testTbl
                  select a.testColumn;
     
      cmbWorkOrder.ItemsSource = query;

Comment: @user779610: Fine, that works too. It would issue a Db query though. If you load the full entities into your `test.ItemsSource` anyway you could just pull the single column for your combo box from the in-memory data, thus avoiding the second DB query. That was the idea in my example above.

Comment: I'm going to use your code as that seems more sensible and efficient.

Comment: @user779610: I've added a small Edit section to my answer.

Comment: Awesome. Definitely cleaner. Thanks again Slauma